# Do Python modules necessarily have to be compiled with the same version as the main core?

Tags: python, visual-studio, dll

Example: If I have an embedded Python 3.2 application compiled with MS VS2010, must all external imports also be compiled with VS2010, or is there some way to successfully import pyd components precompiled in MSVS 2008 ?

I can't seem to find the definitive answer online.

Thanks,
Rob.

Comment: I have vs2010 installed and compiled modules for python 2.7 (built on vs2008) with vs2010's vcvarsall.bat successfully. But in some cases, it might fail.

Comment: Im not looking to recompile those modules, just want to know if I can link them in successfully into my vs2010 build, if they were originally compiled with vs2008.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the two must match - you might "get away with it" some of the time.  The solution is to import .py files.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to mix and match msvcrt.dll versions but it's dangerous (see https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/180754 search for "printf").  You can't allocate with one msvcrt version then free from another (in a different DLL) for instance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit?  Assuming python modules don't use printf, is it ever the case that they would alloc/dealloc memory created in other modules?
Would Py_INC/DECREF(obj) for example, not just call the core function?

Comment: the answer is "probably not" and "if they ever do, expect a segfault".  As long as you call core functions it should be safe, or so I'm told.